# Filtering data from datagridview by daily weekly and monthly basis

Tags: vb.net

Somebody help me. I want to show data in datagridview by Daily, Weekly and monthly basis and calulate total amount on InstallmentAmount column how to do it.
 please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd2F8.jpg)

Comment: Show your _code_ as a minimal complete verifiable (compilable) example. Show where are you stuck, or what error are you getting, and show your effort into solving those problems.

Comment: Show us what you tried. We can't help if we don't know the approach you want to use. We won't just do things for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the [Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcK0C.jpg).

Here is the code,

```
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection = ds.Tables
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource()

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select [InstallmentDate], [CustomerID], [CustomerName], [InstallmentNumber], [InstallmentAmount] from VoucherEntrytbl", conn)
    da.Fill(ds, "VoucherEntrytbl")

    Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view1
    dgvBSDaily.DataSource = view1
    dgvBSDaily.Refresh()

    source1.Filter = DateTimePicker3.Value.Date
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
```